# Show that $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty \implies f(z)$ is not bounded near $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty \implies f(z)$ is not bounded near $z_0$.

(1) : $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty \implies \forall M>0, \exists \delta >0 $ such that $\forall \ 0<|z-z_0|<\delta , |f(z)| > M$.

(2) : $f(z)$ is not bounded near $z_0$ means that $\exists \delta >0 $ such that $\exists \ |z-z_0|<\delta \  , \ \forall M>0 \ ,  \ |f(z)| > M$.

From (1), i obtain a deleted neighborhood about $z_0$ for each value of $M$.

To show (2), i need to find the unique common deleted neighborhood about $z_0$.

How do i find it?

Comment: Are you sure about (2)?

Comment: It should be neighborhood instead of deleted neighborhood. Is that the mistake?

Comment: Doesn't your (2) imply that for all $z$ within a radius of $\delta$ around $z_0$, you have $|f(z)| = \infty$? I think a better definition of unbounded might be: For all $\delta > 0$ and for all $M > 0$, there exists a $z$ with $0 < |z- z_0| < \delta$ such that $|f(z)| > M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is some $M$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $0<|z-z_{0}|<\delta$. Since $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}f(z)=\infty$, find some $\delta'>0$ such that if $0<|z-z_{0}|<\delta'$ then $|f(z)|>M+1$, find some positive integer $N$ large enough such that $1/N<\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$, take $u=z_{0}+1/N$, then $0<|u-z_{0}|<\delta'$ and $0<|u-z_{0}|<\delta$ so we have both $M+1<|f(u)|\leq M$.